# map DTD to a Datalog program

Tags: prolog, dtd, datalog, xsb, xml

Can anyone help me write a Datalog program which is an equivalent of a given DTD.

DTD :

```
<!DOCTYPE abc[
<!ELEMENT abc (xyz*|def+)>
<!ELEMENT xyz (def?)>
<!ELEMENT def (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

Also are there any specific rules that we need to follow while converting a dtd to a corresponding datalog program ?

Comment: FYI. Datalog is a truly declarative logic programming language that syntactically is a subset of Prolog.

If you can answer the above question in Prolog, it is as good as datalog :)

Comment: in Datalog it's far more difficult...

Comment: Yes I know, I just need the datalog program to say true or false (yes/no) based on whether my facts satisfy the rules or not ..